# Convert row to column in influxDB

Tags: select, pivot, grafana, influxdb

In my InfluxDB I want to convert the output of my query from raw to column.
The query is:

```
SELECT max(*) FROM table_X WHERE time > now() - 6m GROUP BY time(5m) fill(previous) ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1
```

The result is:

[image]

But I want to get, for example, this output

[image]

How Can I do?
Help me please

Answer (score 1):

Influx db provides the pivot function feature which will enable the converting rows to columns.

```
pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
```

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/pivot/

**Note:** *Pivot function feature available in 2.x version of the influx db flux queries. In 1.xx version of influx database doesn't support pivot.*

Comment: Can you write me the query based on my output table? Please

Comment: Which version of influx you are using ?

Comment: My version is 1.7.7 :(

Comment: Influx doesn't support this feature in 1.7.x version